# Boolean value getting changed for all - Flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm building a music player, there are two screens - At first screen, list of songs are present in ListView builder and second screen plays the respective music (player screen)

When I play music from the player screen by clicking the play button, the icon changed to pause but the problem is that for other player screen, it also get changed

I'm trying to achieve this using Flutter provider package, I think what happens is that isPlaying boolean is acting up as a global variable in provider class and all of them are consuming the same value, how to tackle this?

```
//Provider class

class MusicPlayerProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  final AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  bool isPlaying = false;



  void playMusic(Map<String, dynamic> songMap) async {
    await audioPlayer.play(UrlSource(songMap['link']));
    isPlaying = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void stopMusic() async {
    await audioPlayer.pause();
    isPlaying = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }


}


// Music Listing Screen
class _MusicListScreenState extends State<MusicListScreen> {

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> songList = [{'name': 'Helix', 'link': 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3', 'singer': 'Alan Walker'}, {'name': 'Lucifer', 'link': 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3', 'singer': 'John Smith'}];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: songList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                primary: Colors.grey
                            ),
                            onPressed: (){
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MusicPlayerScreen(songMap: songList[index])));
                            },
                            child: Text('Go to Player Screen', style: GoogleFonts.oswald(color: Colors.white))
                        )
      },
    );
  }
}


// Music Player Screen

class MusicPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> songMap;
  const MusicPlayerScreen({Key? key, required this.songMap}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MusicPlayerScreen> createState() => _MusicPlayerScreenState();
}

class _MusicPlayerScreenState extends State<MusicPlayerScreen> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<MusicPlayerProvider>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? widgetValue){
        return InkWell(
                            onTap: (){
                              if(value.isPlaying){
                                value.stopMusic();
                              } else {
                                value.playMusic(widget.songMap);
                              }
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              height: 50.0,
                              width: 50.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.grey[300]
                              ),
                              // Icon changed for other music player screen to - problem
                              child: Icon(value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause_circle_filled : Icons.play_circle_fill, color: Colors.white, size: 35.0),
                            ),
                          ),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific to the requirement please. In case of a music player it has to be like that, where the user needs to get to know which song is getting played.

Comment: There is a boolean value in provider class (isPlaying) this is used to keep track of whether music is playing or not (if playing, show pause icon else play icon) but what happening is that it gets changed for all musics at same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your provider you can track the song that is playing instead of just `isPlaying` bool. This way you can tell which song is playing (if any) and show play/pause button accordingly.

UPD: also I would recommend moving song list to provider as well. So screens would just display a state and provider would handle the data.

Comment: how to track the song whether the music is playing or not without boolean value? @obywan

Comment: You can have some variable `String?` that would represent the key from your dictionary (Map). If it's `null` then nothing is playing right now, if there is a value, then you know what song is playing.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you have a list, then your variable should be an `int?` and that will represent an index from your list. Say `int? currentSongIndex;` When you tap play you assign song's index from your list to it. And on pause you set `null` . Then you can check if `currentSongIndex == null` then nothing is playing, otherwise you know what song is on right now.

Comment: Man, you are awesome! Why didn't I think of it? haha! Worked perfectly

Comment: but there is one problem in this approach! Let's say, I played any one of the musics, after that, I tried play any other music (when one is already being played without pausing), then when I click on play button for second music, it executed the "else" code (the pause one)

Comment: because currentSongIndex is no longer null and it would then fall into "else" block irrespective of playing other music @obywan

Comment: Any idea? How could I tackle this problem?

Comment: Never mind! Figured it out! Thank you for being so helpful